# Android - Convert GMT time to Locale time

Tags: java, android, datetime-format

I am trying to convert UTC time to user's Locale time. However, I am getting back the same UTC time. 
Apparently, setting the time zone to locale/default does not work.

Another method seems to be available using Instant, but requires API level 26.

This is my input date in string: "2020-01-16T19:44:48.303+0000".
I am expecting to have the date and time in this format: "M/dd/yy - h:mm aa"

```
private String toLocaleTime(String timeStr){
    // Date date;
        SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'+0000'");
        simpleDateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());

        String localeTime = "";
        try {
            //date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss", Locale.US).parse(timeStr);
            localeTime = simpleDateFormat.format(simpleDateFormat.parse(timeStr));

        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        //String str = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss", Locale.US).format(date);
        Log.d("LocaleTime", ""+ localeTime);
        return localeTime;
}
```

Comment: There is no such thing as "Locale time". E.g. `Locale.US` covers a lot of time zones, Pacific, Mountain, Central, and Eastern being the major 4 of them.

Comment: As an aside consider throwing away the long outmoded and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` and friends, and adding [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) to your Android project in order to use java.time, the modern Java date and time API. It is so much nicer to work with.

Comment: You basic error is trying to store your date and time in a string. Store them in a proper date-time object such as an `OffsetDateTime`, it’s a class from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) (which doesn’t necessarily require API level 26, see my previous comment). Then when you need to display the time to the user, convert to user’s time zone (which is something different from locale) and format into a string (in the proper locale).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You tell the *parsing* date formatter to parse using UTC time zone, the tell the *formatting* date formatter to format using the default time zone (by not telling it anything):

```
String input = "2020-01-16T19:44:48.303+0000";

SimpleDateFormat inputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'+0000'");
inputFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
Date date = inputFormat.parse(input);

SimpleDateFormat outputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS");
// Not needed:  outputFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());
String output = outputFormat.format(date);

System.out.println("input:  " + input);
System.out.println("output: " + output);
System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat("zzzz  XX").format(date));
```

*Output*

```
input:  2020-01-16T19:44:48.303+0000
output: 2020-01-16T14:44:48.303
Eastern Standard Time  -0500
```

Answer (score 1):

## *java.time*

A `Locale` has nothing to do with the content of a date-time object. A locale only comes into the picture when generating text to represent the value of the date-time object. I suspect your intention is to adjust from an offset-from-UTC of hours-minutes-seconds to the wall-clock time used by the people of a particular region (a time zone).

Never use `SimoleDateFormat` or `Date` or `Calendar`. These terrible date-time classes were supplanted by *java.time* years ago. For Android before 26, **add the [*ThreeTenABP*](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) library** to your project.

> This is my input date in string: "2020-01-16T19:44:48.303+0000"

Tip: The *java.time* classes and other date-time frameworks work better if you include the colon character between the hours and seconds in the offset: `+00:00`.

If all your inputs have the same offset, replace that part of the string.

```
String input = "2020-01-16T19:44:48.303+0000".replace( "+0000" , "+00:00" ) ;
```

Parse as an `Instant`, a moment in UTC.

```
Instant instant = Instant.parse( input ) ;
```

Generate a string in your desired format. Do you really want one-digit month with two digit day? And one digit hour with two digit minute?

```
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "M/dd/uu - h:mm a" ).withLocale( locale ) ;
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Africa/Tunis" ) ;
String output = instant.atZone( z ).format( z ) ;
```

I suggest you instead let *java.time* automatically localize for you with `DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDateTime`.

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

Comment: @  I had mentioned *ThreeTenABP* in the last sentence of the 2nd paragraph. I added bolding. And I added the "About *java.time*" section at bottom.